# How can I run Play framework in HTTPS only in the dev mode?

Tags: java, https, playframework, playframework-1.x

I'd like to run Play Framework over HTTPS **only** in the development mode and I've done so using the following bit of configuration:

```
https.port=9443
trustmanager.algorithm=JKS
keystore.file=conf/certificate.jks
keystore.password=password
certificate.password=password
application.mode=dev
%prodenv.application.mode=prod
```

This works when I run `play run` but in production we run `play run --%prodenv` and I want to disable HTTPS as the HTTPS is handled by Nginx. I'm lost with how to do this. I would like to do this via the configuration file and not via additional command-line arguments as it does defy the purpose of having all my application configuration in the `application.conf` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than have two configuration files, I achieved this by using just one. In order to run the app, I run `play run --%dev` and this is what the configuration looks like.

```
%dev.https.port=9443
%dev.trustmanager.algorithm=JKS
%dev.keystore.file=conf/certificate.jks
%dev.keystore.password=password
%dev.certificate.password=password
```

Comment: I haven't seen that format before. Where is it documented please?

Comment: Ah: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.1/ids (sorry -- you only go looking when you believe something exists! -- thanks for bringing this to my attention)

Answer (score 9):

One way to do it is to have two confs file: `application.conf` and `prod.conf`

`application.conf` stays the way it is and `prod.conf` would look something like

```
include "application.conf"
https.port = myProdPort

### other params to be overwritten
```

when launching your application in prod you can do

```
play run -Dconfig.file=/mypath/prod.conf
```

Answer (score 5):

sbt `run -Dhttps.port=9443 -Dhttp.port=disabled`

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the other answer by Johan, I do it the reverse way: my `application.conf` is for prod and I run a `dev.conf` just in development:

```
include "application.conf"
https.port = devPort
```

And run locally like so:

```
play run -Dconfig.file=dev.conf
```

This way you don't have to change any configuration on your prod server.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the `https.port` param from your conf file and pass it in via the command line, when you run it in development mode:

```
play run -Dhttp.port=9443
```

See: [Sprecifying server address and port](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ProductionConfiguration#Specifying-the-HTTP-server-address-and-port-using-system-properties)

Comment: Please see my edit. I'd like to do this via the `application.conf` file.

Comment: Have you considered using different conf files for dev and prod?

Answer (score 0):

Play framework runs using Netty server you can overwrite the server configuration using `-D` parameters.

In `sbt` it can be done like:

```
sbt "project pepe-grillo-server" "run -Dhttps.port=42443 -Dhttp.port=disabled"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom ssl engine provider `CustomSSLEngineProvider` you can use below command to run netty in ssl mode.

```
./sbt "-Dhttps.port=9443" "-Dplay.server.https.engineProvider=services.https.CustomSSLEngineProvider" "-Dconfig.resource=<config file> run
```

Once the server is up and running you can curl the endpoint to check cert validity.

```
curl -v https://127.0.0.1:9443
```